# Facebook pixel fires always not only after ad engagement

Tags: facebook

i am just starting with facebook marketing and have a question about the facebook pixel. We create a campaign with ads, created the facebook pixel and added it on the website for the purchase event. Thats all good and works, but we see that the pixel fires always, where it should only fire when the person who purchased something actually came through the ad. I thought that the pixel would only fire if a person came through the ad to the web site. Is that wrong (I mean it looks like it is wrong), or differently asked, how can we measure which purchases were initiated through the ad, or can the pixel only fire for people that came through the ad?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i at least found out a few things:

1. The pixel fires always. Doesnt matter if a person came through the ad, or just came to the website from somewhere else. That means that the pixel statistic is not helpful in that way.
2. To see conversions from an ad, the report directly for the ad (or adset) is the place to go. There is a field for "Result" which should show the number of conversions that you defined for the ad set to be tracked.
3. Dont mistake the result field with the website conversions. I thought that this number should be the same but it is not. Website conversions tracks all conversions, even if the adset is configured to only track one specific conversion.

I still find it a little confusing, and not all doesnt make sense yet. But at least a bit better already.